# Jenkins: coordinating multiple pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am developing software for an embedded device. The steps involved in building and verifying it all are complicated: creating the build environment (via containers), building the actual SD card image, running unit tests, automated tests on target hardware, license compliance checks and so on - details aren't important here.

Currently I have this in one long declarative Jenkinsfile as a multibranch-pipeline (for all intents and purpose here, we're doing gitflow). In doing this I've hit a limit on the size of a Jenkinsfile (https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-37984) and can't actually get all the stages in that I want to.

It's too big so i need to cut this massive pipeline up. I broke this all up in little pipeline jobs with parameters to pass data/context between each part of the pipeline and came up with something like this:

[image: Jobs and their dependencies]

I've colour-coded the A and B artifacts as they're used a lot and the lines would make things messy. What this tries to show is an order of running things, where things in a column depend on artifacts created in column to the left.

I'm struggling to discover how to do the "waiting" for multiple upstream jobs (for instance in Job Foxtrot in the diagram) before starting another downstream job that depends on them.

I specifically do not want to turn each column in the diagram into a parallel group of things, because for instance Job Delta might take 2 minutes but Job Charlie take 20 minutes. The exact duration of each job is variable and unpredictable as for some parameter combinations will mean building from scratch and others will cause an existing artifact to be output.

I think I need something like the join plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/join/), but for pipeline jobs (join only works on freestyle jobs and is quite aged).

The one approach I've explored is to have a "controller" job (maybe job Alpha in the diagram?) that uses the build step (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/_) with the wait parameter set to false to trigger the downstream jobs in correct order, with the correct parameters. It would involve searching Jenkins.instance.getItems() to locate the Runs for the downstream projects, which have an upstream cause that matches the currently executing "controller" job. This involves polling waiting for the job to appear and then polling for the job to complete. This feels like I'm "doing it wrong". Below is the source for this polling approach - be gentle, i'm new to groovy!

**Is this polling approach a good way? What problems could I encounter with this approach?** Should I be using the ItemListener Jenkins ExtensionPoint and writing a plugin to do this sort of thing in a generic way? Is there another way I've not found?

I feel like I'm not "holding it right" when it comes to the overall pipeline design/architecture here.

Finally after writing this I notice that Jobs India, Juliet and Kilo could be collapsed into a single Job, but I don't think that solve much.

```
@NonCPS
Integer getTriggeredBuildNumber(String project, String causeJobName, Integer causeBuildNumber) {
    //find the job/project first
    def job = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.class).find { job -> job.getFullName() == project }
    //find a build for this job that was caused by the current build
    def build = job.getBuilds().find { build -> 
        build.getCauses().findAll{ it.class == hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause.class }.find { cause -> 
            cause.getUpstreamProject() == causeJobName && cause.getUpstreamBuild() == causeBuildNumber
        } != null
    }
    if(build != null) {
        return build.getNumber()
    } else {
        return -1
    }
}

@NonCPS
Boolean isBuildComplete(String jobName, Integer buildNumber) {
    def job = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.class).find { job -> job.getFullName() == jobName }
    if(job) {
        def build = job.getBuildByNumber(buildNumber)
        return build.isBuilding() == false && build.getResult() != null
    } else {
        println "WARNING: job '" + jobName + "' not found."
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two viable basic approaches: 1) break down your pipeline into multiple ones, i.e. multiple jobs, and you have to deal with the job synchronization; and 2) move a lot of your code into shared pipeline libraries, which somewhat allows unit-tests, as well as simplify the higher level logic in your Jenkinsfile. Can you indicate if you have a preference for one versus the other ? Obviously the answer would differ greatly.

Comment: Thanks for asking :-) I would prefer an answer about how to synchronise multiple jobs. Particularly on how to trigger a downstream job after all it's dependent upstream jobs have completed.

Answer (score 0):

We've hit the "Code too large" too many times, but the way to cope with it is to refactor your pipeline to remain deep under the limit. The following may be used:

1. You can run a combination of scripted and declarative pipeline. So some stages in the beginning and/or in the end may be refactored out.
2. You can build some of the parallel stages dynamically. This code would not be counted towards the limited code size.
3. Lastly, the issue mentions transformation variables, and that can help too.

We used the combination of the above and have expanded our pipeline well beyond what it was when we first encountered the issue you're facing.

Comment: So your answer to the question is "No, don't have multiple pipelines/jobs, stick with the single pipeline and refactor it"?

Comment: Wholeheartedly. IIUC there's no business reason to refactor, just a Jenkins limitation?